# Toggle Hamburger Menu Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, hamburger-menu

My Hamburger menu is not working properly, that's it is not showing the menu items whenever a user clicks on it. It is however acting properly on the other functionality whenever it is clicked. I have tried every possible trick and i haven't managed to get it to work properly.I am not sure what is the challenge with my javascript because i believe that should be were the issues are. Below is my code:

```js
const hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
const navbar = document.querySelector(".nav__list");

hamburger.addEventListener("click", ()=> {
    navbar.classList.toggle("open");
});


const hamburgerBtn = document.querySelector('.hamburger');
let hamburgerOpen = false;

hamburgerBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (!hamburgerOpen) {
        hamburgerBtn.classList.add('open');
        hamburgerOpen = true;
    } else {
        hamburgerBtn.classList.remove('open');
        hamburgerOpen = false;
    }
});
```

```css
:root {
    --fw-normal: 400;
    --fw-dark: 600;
    --fw-bold: 700;

    /***Colors***/
    --clr-primary: #333;
    --clr-text: #fafafa;
    --clr-blue: #22a7ff;
    --clr-purple: #871e5f;
    --clr-green: #19a356;
    --clr-yellow: #ffff2e;
    --clr-red: #cd1a21; 
    --clr-orange: #ff4500;

    /*** Font and Typography ***/
    --ff-body: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    --ff-header: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    --fs-header: 4.5rem;
    --fs-header1: 2.5rem;
    --fs-header2: 1.5rem;
    --fs-header3: 1.2rem;
    --fs-lg-para: 1.1rem;
    --fs-md-para: 1rem;
    --fs--sm-para: .938rem;

    /*** z index ***/
    --z-index: 99;
}





/***************************************************
2. #Global Styles
***************************************************/

*, ::before, ::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: var(--ff-body);
    background: var(--clr-text);
    color: var(--clr-primary);
    font-size: var(--fs-para);
    line-height: 1.6;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    padding:  1.25em;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transition:all .5s;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: var(--ff-header);
    margin: 0;
}

p {
    margin: 0;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

/* img {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
} */





/************************************************
3. #Typography
************************************************/

    /* Navigation Bar & Hero Section*/
.bg-hero {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background: var(--clr-blue);
    transition: .5s;
}

.navbar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 2.5em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}



@media screen and (max-width: 48em) {
    .nav__list {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: -100%;
        width: 80%;
        height: 80%;
        background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.3);
        backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
        z-index: var(--z-index);
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        transition: .2s;
        display: none;
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

.open {
    right: 0;
}

.nav__link {
    color: var(--clr-text);
    font-weight: var(--fw-normal);
    font-size: var(--fs-lg-para);
}

.nav__link:hover {
    color: var(--clr-purple);
}

.shopping-cart {
    margin-right: 2em;
    color: var(--clr-text);
}

.social__media {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding-left: 3em;
    margin-top: 3em;
}

.sm__link {
    background: var(--clr-text);
    width: 2.7em;
    height: 2.7em;
    margin: 1em .625em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.sm__link i {
    transition: .1s linear;
}

.sm__link:hover i {
    transform: scale(1.5);
}

.sm__facebook {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: #4267b2;
}

.sm__twitter {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: #1da1f2;
}

.sm__instagram {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: #000;
}

.social__contact {
    display: none;
}





/*****************************************************
4. #Components
*****************************************************/

/*4.1 Cart Basket*/
.cart-item {
    background: linear-gradient(-270deg, #ff7800 8.6%, #ff5000 99.58%, #ff5000 100%);
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 1px 3px 2px;
}

 /*4.2 Buttons*/
 .btn-main {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 18em;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 3em;
    padding: .5em 1.25em;
    border-radius: 1.563em;
    margin-top: 2.5em;
    background: linear-gradient(-270deg, #ff7800 8.6%, #ff5000 99.58%, #ff5000 100%);
    color: var(--clr-text);
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: .88rem;
}

.fa-angle-right {
    color: #ff7800;
    background: var(--clr-text);
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: .438em;
    margin-right: -.938em;
}

.btn-main:focus,
.fa-arrow-right:focus {
    color: var(--clr-primary);
    opacity: 0.1;
}

.btn-main:hover,
.fa-arrow-right:hover {
    color: var(--clr-primary);
}

/*4.3 Hamburger*/
.hamburger {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    right: 2%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-5%,-50%);
    z-index: var(--z-index);
}

.hamburger-btn {
    width: 20px;
    height: 3px;
    background: var(--clr-text);
    margin: .625em;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.hamburger-btn::before,
.hamburger-btn::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width:20px;
    height: 3px;
    background: var(--clr-text);
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.hamburger-btn::before {
    transform: translateY(-7px);
}

.hamburger-btn::after {
    transform: translateY(7px);
}

.hamburger.open .hamburger-btn {
    transform: translateX(-50px);
    background: transparent;
}

.hamburger.open .hamburger-btn::before {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(35px, -35px);
}

.hamburger.open .hamburger-btn::after {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(35px, 35px);
}
```

```html
<section class="bg-hero">
         <nav class="navbar">
            <a href="#" class="company-brand"><img src="#" alt="#" class="#"><span>X&L Limited</span></a>
            <ul class="nav__list">
               <li class="nav__list-item"><a href="" class="nav__link"></a></li>
               <li class="nav__list-item"><a href="" class="nav__link">Products</a></li>
               <li class="nav__list-item"><a href="" class="nav__link">Our Story</a></li>
               <li class="nav__list-item"><a href="" class="nav__link">Blog</a></li>
               <li class="nav__list-item"><a href="" class="nav__link">Contact Us</a></li>
               <div class="social__media">
                  <a href="#" class="sm__link"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f sm__facebook"></i></a>
                  <a href="#" class="sm__link"><i class="fab fa-twitter sm__twitter"></i></a>
                  <a href="#" class="sm__link"><i class="fab fa-instagram sm__instagram"></i></a>
               </div>
            </ul>
            <div>
               <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart fa-lg shopping-cart">&nbsp;<span class="cart-item">0</span></i>
            </div>
            <div class="hamburger">
               <div class="hamburger-btn"></div>
            </div>
         </nav>
         <div class="hero">
            <div class="contentBox">
               <h1 class="hero-title">Do you like <br><span>Smooth Skin?</span></h1>
               <p class="hero-para">Naturally, the skin is supposed to be smooth and soft, however, the only insurance for dry and oily skin is skincare products that consistently offer effective skin protection. To protect dry and oily skin, make the smart choice, because the choice is yours, and it's simple.</p>
               <a class="btn-main" href="#">View Our Products &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-angle-right fa-lg"></i></a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove display:none from your `.nav__list`, add `opacity:1` to .open and also edit your code on mobile version.

```js
const hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
const navbar = document.querySelector(".nav__list");

hamburger.addEventListener("click", ()=> {
    navbar.classList.toggle("open");
});


const hamburgerBtn = document.querySelector('.hamburger');
let hamburgerOpen = false;

hamburgerBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (!hamburgerOpen) {
        hamburgerBtn.classList.add('open');
        hamburgerOpen = true;
    } else {
        hamburgerBtn.classList.remove('open');
        hamburgerOpen = false;
    }
});
```

```css
:root {
    --fw-normal: 400;
    --fw-dark: 600;
    --fw-bold: 700;

    /***Colors***/
    --clr-primary: #333;
    --clr-text: #fafafa;
    --clr-blue: #22a7ff;
    --clr-purple: #871e5f;
    --clr-green: #19a356;
    --clr-yellow: #ffff2e;
    --clr-red: #cd1a21; 
    --clr-orange: #ff4500;

    /*** Font and Typography ***/
    --ff-body: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    --ff-header: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    --fs-header: 4.5rem;
    --fs-header1: 2.5rem;
    --fs-header2: 1.5rem;
    --fs-header3: 1.2rem;
    --fs-lg-para: 1.1rem;
    --fs-md-para: 1rem;
    --fs--sm-para: .938rem;

    /*** z index ***/
    --z-index: 99;
}





/***************************************************
2. #Global Styles
***************************************************/

*, ::before, ::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: var(--ff-body);
    background: var(--clr-text);
    color: var(--clr-primary);
    font-size: var(--fs-para);
    line-height: 1.6;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    padding:  1.25em;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transition:all .5s;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: var(--ff-header);
    margin: 0;
}

p {
    margin: 0;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

/* img {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
} */





/************************************************
3. #Typography
************************************************/

    /* Navigation Bar & Hero Section*/
.bg-hero {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background: var(--clr-blue);
    transition: .5s;
}

.navbar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 2.5em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.nav__list {
        right: -100%;
        opacity: 0;
    }
.open{
  
        right: 0;
  opacity:1;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 48em) {
    .nav__list {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: -100%;
        width: 80%;
        height: 80%;
        background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.3);
        backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
        z-index: var(--z-index);
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        transition: .2s;
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

html .open {
    right: 0;
  opacity:1;
}

.nav__link {
    color: var(--clr-text);
    font-weight: var(--fw-normal);
    font-size: var(--fs-lg-para);
}

.nav__link:hover {
    color: var(--clr-purple);
}

.shopping-cart {
    margin-right: 2em;
    color: var(--clr-text);
}

.social__media {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding-left: 3em;
    margin-top: 3em;
}

.sm__link {
    background: var(--clr-text);
    width: 2.7em;
    height: 2.7em;
    margin: 1em .625em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.sm__link i {
    transition: .1s linear;
}

.sm__link:hover i {
    transform: scale(1.5);
}

.sm__facebook {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: #4267b2;
}

.sm__twitter {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: #1da1f2;
}

.sm__instagram {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: #000;
}

.social__contact {
    display: none;
}





/*****************************************************
4. #Components
*****************************************************/

/*4.1 Cart Basket*/
.cart-item {
    background: linear-gradient(-270deg, #ff7800 8.6%, #ff5000 99.58%, #ff5000 100%);
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 1px 3px 2px;
}
 /*4.2 Buttons*/
 .btn-main {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 18em;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 3em;
    padding: .5em 1.25em;
    border-radius: 1.563em;
    margin-top: 2.5em;
    background: linear-gradient(-270deg, #ff7800 8.6%, #ff5000 99.58%, #ff5000 100%);
    color: var(--clr-text);
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: .88rem;
}

.fa-angle-right {
    color: #ff7800;
    background: var(--clr-text);
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: .438em;
    margin-right: -.938em;
}

.btn-main:focus,
.fa-arrow-right:focus {
    color: var(--clr-primary);
    opacity: 0.1;
}

.btn-main:hover,
.fa-arrow-right:hover {
    color: var(--clr-primary);
}

/*4.3 Hamburger*/
.hamburger {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    right: 2%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-5%,-50%);
    z-index: var(--z-index);
}

.hamburger-btn {
    width: 20px;
    height: 3px;
    background: var(--clr-text);
    margin: .625em;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.hamburger-btn::before,
.hamburger-btn::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width:20px;
    height: 3px;
    background: var(--clr-text);
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.hamburger-btn::before {
    transform: translateY(-7px);
}

.hamburger-btn::after {
    transform: translateY(7px);
}

.hamburger.open .hamburger-btn {
    transform: translateX(-50px);
    background: transparent;
}

.hamburger.open .hamburger-btn::before {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(35px, -35px);
}

.hamburger.open .hamburger-btn::after {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(35px, 35px);
}
```

```html
<section class="bg-hero">
         <nav class="navbar">
            <a href="#" class="company-brand"><img src="#" alt="#" class="#"><span>X&L Limited</span></a>
            <ul class="nav__list">
               <li class="nav__list-item"><a href="" class="nav__link"></a></li>
               <li class="nav__list-item"><a href="" class="nav__link">Products</a></li>
               <li class="nav__list-item"><a href="" class="nav__link">Our Story</a></li>
               <li class="nav__list-item"><a href="" class="nav__link">Blog</a></li>
               <li class="nav__list-item"><a href="" class="nav__link">Contact Us</a></li>
               <div class="social__media">
                  <a href="#" class="sm__link"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f sm__facebook"></i></a>
                  <a href="#" class="sm__link"><i class="fab fa-twitter sm__twitter"></i></a>
                  <a href="#" class="sm__link"><i class="fab fa-instagram sm__instagram"></i></a>
               </div>
            </ul>
            <div>
               <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart fa-lg shopping-cart">&nbsp;<span class="cart-item">0</span></i>
            </div>
            <div class="hamburger">
               <div class="hamburger-btn"></div>
            </div>
         </nav>
         <div class="hero">
            <div class="contentBox">
               <h1 class="hero-title">Do you like <br><span>Smooth Skin?</span></h1>
               <p class="hero-para">Naturally, the skin is supposed to be smooth and soft, however, the only insurance for dry and oily skin is skincare products that consistently offer effective skin protection. To protect dry and oily skin, make the smart choice, because the choice is yours, and it's simple.</p>
               <a class="btn-main" href="#">View Our Products &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-angle-right fa-lg"></i></a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </section>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It is now working fine.

Comment: @Tendekai anytime :) click on the (Answered bottom) then. ;)

Comment: I have done as you requested sorry for having not clicked the accept button